# Instagram API: get home timeline

Tags: instagram-api

Is there a way for me to get the logged in user's home time line in Instagram API?

I have tried hitting the https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users_media_recent_self

but I only get the posts done by the logged in user and not by friends

Comment: you are in sandbox name so it only shows sandbox authorized users in api, until your app is reviewed and approved